# What is this type of authentication with device id and token?

Tags: authentication, oauth, account-security

I'm trying to understand this strategy of authentication that I'm using to access resources of an enterprise.

Basically, they have given me `clientId` and `clientSecret`, which I use to generate `deviceId` and `deviceToken`. Following that, I use them in web services call to get `authToken` and use it in Authentication header `bearer access_token` to access content.

My question is

1. What kind of authentication is this? It doesn't look like OAuth to
   me because they have callback handlers.
2. Can you explain `clientId`, `clientSecret`, `deviceId` and `deviceToken`?
   A little guideline on what parts I need to know in order to build an
   authentication system like that?

Comment: I am not an OAuth export, but this looks like OAuth 2 to me. OAuth providers often implement it in non-standard ways. For example, Facebook, IIRC, had a non-standard client-side redirect parameter.

Comment: any reference to OAuth2 examples please

Comment: @user2727195 look at google analytics oauth2 or paypal oauth2 ..either the documentation or the application its self... paypal documentation should do you fine on understand oauth2

Answer (score 1):

1. In my experience, bearer is usually OAuth2.

A very popular authentication library is passport.js

They have over 300+  authentication strategies and provide examples on all of them.

Here is the site: http://passportjs.org

Click on strategies and then search for "bearer" and then you can click on one and look through the example code.

2. OAuth2 is a framework, usually used to authroize special permissions. I believe they are using those specific Id and token to determine what kind of "authorization" you have to the enterprise

Below is from following source: http://www.seedbox.com/en/blog/2015/06/05/oauth-2-vs-json-web-tokens-comment-securiser-un-api/

```
What is OAuth2?
OAuth2, alternatively, is not a protocol it is a security framework. It details how multiple different roles, users in your system, server side apps like an API, and clients such as websites or native mobile apps, can authenticate with each other.



Roles
Both applications and users can be one of the following:

Resource Owner
Resource Server
Client Application
Authorization Server
Client Types

A client is something that consumes your API. It can be one of the following two types:

Confidential
Public
Client Profiles

There are also client profiles specified by the framework, that describe the kind of application type. They can be:

Web Application
User Agent
Native
Authorization Grants

An authorization grant is a set of permissions given by the resource owner to a client application. They can take the following forms:

Authorization Code
Implicit
Resource Owner Password Credentials
Client Credentials
Endpoints

In order for all of us this to work the following endpoints are required:

Authorization Endpoint
Token Endpoint
Redirection Endpoint
```

Comment: it occurred to me after reading some posts earlier in the day that oauth2 is not final, and few people left from specs team

Comment: @user2727195 the final version of the oAuth2 spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749 ...

Comment: @schroeder i found the terms client id and secret and understand them but I don't understand device id and device token?